# Rest parameters when overloading with optional

Tags: typescript

When overloading functions I sometimes use the following pattern:

```
export function foo(a: string): void;
export function foo(b: number): void;
export function foo(a: string, b: number): void;
export function foo(...args: [string] | [number] | [string, number]): void {
    /* ... */
}
```

This makes it easy to determine which of the prototypes is used, e.g. if `args.length === 2` then `args` is known to be `[string, number]`. With more complex types (consider if instead of `string` and `number` you have two interfaces) this can simplify a great deal.

However, I cannot get this working when using optional parameters:

```
export function foo(a?: string): void;
//              ~~~ error TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
export function foo(...args: [] | [string]): void {
    return;
}
```

I know I can simply add another overload without the optional parameter but the combinations would quickly become unmanageable.

```
export function foo(): void;
export function foo(a: string): void;
export function foo(...args: [] | [string]): void {
    return;
}
```

A more concrete example of this would be:

```
interface Foo {
  /* ... */
}

interface Bar {
  /* ... */
}

interface Baz {
  /* ... */
}

function awesomeFunction(foo?: Foo, bar?: Bar): void;
function awesomeFunction(baz: Baz, foo?: Foo, bar?: Bar): void;
function awesomeFunction(...args:
  | [Foo | undefined, Bar | undefined]
  | [Baz, Foo | undefined, Bar | undefined]
): void {
  /* ... */
}
```

Since I know that if `args[0]` is a `Baz` I would know the rest of the elements in `args` as well. It does however not work as seen above with the `foo` function.

Typing out all the permutations would become a lot of variants and typing out each parameter as `arg1?: Foo | Baz, arg2: Foo | Bar, arg3: Bar` means I have to typecheck for impossible variants.

Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [optional tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NB8AzW)?  While there are arguably equivalences between optional tuple elements and unions of non-optional tuples of varying lengths, I'm not sure you gain anything by trying to convince the compiler of that. If that fully address the question I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That seems to be what I'm missing, that is, I simply did not know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's essentially a [direct equivalence between function parameter lists and tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions). In particular, [optional function parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) like in `(x?: string) => void` correspond to [optional tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) like `[string?]` (or, when you use [tuple element labels](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements), `[x?: string]`).

That means you could write your [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) implementations like this:

```
function foo(a?: string): void;
function foo(...args: [string?]): void {
}

function awesomeFunction(foo?: Foo, bar?: Bar): void;
function awesomeFunction(baz: Baz, foo?: Foo, bar?: Bar): void;
function awesomeFunction(...args: [Foo?, Bar?] | [Baz, Foo?, Bar?]): void {
}
```

Indeed if the return types are identical for all the call signatures, you don't even need overloads:

```
function bar(...args: [a?: string]): void { }
// bar(a?: string | undefined): void
```

and a function accepting a union of rest tuples looks like an overloaded function when you call it:

```
function awesomeFunction(...args:
  [foo?: Foo, bar?: Bar] | [baz: Baz, foo?: Foo, bar?: Bar]
): void { }
// 1/2 awesomeFunction(foo?: Foo | undefined, bar?: Bar | undefined): void
// 2/2 awesomeFunction(baz: Baz, foo?: Foo | undefined, bar?: Bar | undefined): void
```

And while there are arguably a relationship between `[string?]` and `[string] | []`, there's probably no point in trying to force the compiler to see it when optional tuple elements are available.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgJbAAuEATgGYLIBiA9o3oUUgPQBUSAdP0i4c2AX3xtSFGnSQAhEJVbtOPfr0HCiYieSq1EckDgLLufAUNHjxRagFdg8MsUbAk1ZgAoQAfgBcSFBklKQA5gCUAQBujMQAJgDcbPaOzq7uXmoKoVABANpBIcChPgC6kUgx8UpI2rYOTi5uIADu0IyQ9A1pwJ4ejP5ITIwANEgARgqD8pQVVYnJ3U1Ire2dS66ek1gB8lhj-YPDY5OU0wpzsQv1qcurUB0QXbebWZQ5+cM+YzNlSAA+SDyezGXx+U3K0SuNW0bFAkFgMgAIq4yAA5CAQOIAeSiVAwjBAcSgNRujXSp08bw+QN8AUKYUhlWhuFqbCIHA4EwU3kGDOKAKQDjiEGopCxl3iNnYKXJzTaD3WL161Ny7PYeUOAWO3LOuwUpUFeW2+v2GQG2uYJym+sopXVkrieDZpi5AEYOAAmFYKx7POV9ZhHZiC4Wi8Vxa16wyKQFhsXACVQqWupCer0+tZPDa9E2GM1aoYhuPAEUJrFR86xoWl8OJuKOqz4ERAA)